# Sidekiq worker management on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, background-process, sidekiq

I have a few Sidekiq (rubygem) workers that I am currently managing with the built in daemonization feature.

How can I install my workers as a system service that restarts automatically if it crashes? The one requirement is that it must not require using `sudo`, since it has to run under the regular deploy user and I'm deploying with capistrano v3, so no `sudo` allowed.

Comment: No idea about how to manage services without being root, I'm interested about it too

Comment: have you tried http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#what-is-upstart ; and can run as non-priv user.. http://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users ; if this seems like the right fit i got some config examples i can share that works for me